# Unable to install php mongodb driver on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, pecl

I have been trying to install php driver for mongodb on Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS. Tried to install as follows :

`sudo pecl install mongodb`
output is `No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/mongodb"`

Also i tried to install the legacy version

`sudo pecl install mongo`
output is `No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/mongo"`

So, i downloaded the latest package for mogodb php driver from "pecl.php.net/package/mongodb"

```
mongodb-1.1.2.tgz
```

Placed it on linux file system and tried installing as below.

```
sudo pecl install mongodb-1.1.2.tgz
```

output is `could not extract the package.xml file from "mongodb-1.1.2.tgz"
install failed`

So, i extracted the package using command `tar -xvzf mongodb-1.1.2.tgz`

I am able to see the `package.xml` there.

I copied `package.xml` to the directory `mongodb-1.1.2` and tried intalling mongodb by passing the package.xml directly as below

```
sudo pecl install package.xml
```

This is the output:

```
    349 source files, building
running: phpize
sh: 1: phpize: not found
If the command failed with 'phpize: not found' then you need to install php5-dev packageYou can do it by running 'apt-get install php5-dev' as a root userERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Tried to install php5-dev as below:

`sudo apt-get install php5-dev`

output is as below:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
 php5 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php5 (>= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.18) but it is not going to be installed or
                 libapache2-mod-php5filter (>= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.18) but it is not going to be installed or
                 php5-cgi (>= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.18) but it is not going to be installed or
                 php5-fpm (>= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.18) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: php5-common (>= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.18) but it is not going to be installed
 php5-dev : Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libtool (>= 2.2)
            Depends: php5-common (>= 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.18) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Any help/guidance is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: why are your first couple error samples saying "mogo"? Is that a typo here, or didyou really type "mogo" and fix the command sample but leave the error message intact?

Comment: @MarcB, yes it's a typo it should be `mongo`